Need help summarising data at asset level while also evaluating at blockgroup level too
I have a table of assets which belong to blockgroups which belong to stations. Assets<Blockgroup<Station. I'm trying to filter the table down to a smaller asset list based on some conditions. A few are extremely easy to do and can just be filtered on a table visual, eg get rid of all Bus Stop BlockGroups. The harder part I'm finding is eg. I want to remove all footbridge assets if they're the only footbridge at the station, or I want to filter out all the access routes when a station has more than 2 access routes.
I think If I made a summarised table at the station level with the number of each asset for each block group I could relate this back to the asset level table, but I'm struggling to get this to work atm. It should be easy:
Summarize('Assetdata', 'Assetdata'[stationcode], 'Assetdata'[Blockgroup], "Asset Count", Calculate(Count('Assetdata'[Assetname]), 'Assetdata'[stationcode])))

but I get the error about converting value to of type text to true or false, so clearly I need some kind of function/operator in the Filter part of my Calculation. Even if I then get the summary table made I'm not sure how I would apply that back to the asset level.
Any help is greatly appreciated, unsure how to label this problem so any help there too would be appreciated.



AssetName
BlockGroupName
Station_Code__c




zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Abbey Wood
zSet_QA Questions
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Abbey Wood
zSet_Station
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(10)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(13)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(16)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(2)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(23)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(25)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(27)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(29)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(31)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(31)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Access Route(7)
zSet_Access Route
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Baby changing   room(37)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Bus stop(12)
zSet_Bus Stop
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Bus stop(26)
zSet_Bus Stop
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Bus stop(28)
zSet_Bus Stop
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Car Parking -   Disabled(1)
zSet_Access Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Car Parking -   Disabled(6)
zSet_Access Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Car Parking -   Disabled(9)
zSet_Access Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Concourse(33)
zSet_Concourse
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Concourse(33)
zSet_Gateline
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Concourse(33)
zSet_Ticket - Service-Retail Vending
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Concourse(34)
zSet_Concourse
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Concourse(34)
zSet_Gateline
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Concourse(34)
zSet_Ticket - Service-Retail Vending
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Cycle parking(30)
zSet_Cycle Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Cycle racks(11)
zSet_Cycle Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Cycle racks(14)
zSet_Cycle Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Cycle racks(24)
zSet_Cycle Parking
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Escalator(47)
zSet_Escalators & Moving Walkways
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Escalator(53)
zSet_Escalators & Moving Walkways
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge -   Covered(46)
zSet_Bridge Decks
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge -   Covered(46)
zSet_Footbridge Covered
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge -   Open(49)
zSet_Bridge Decks
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge -   Open(49)
zSet_Footbridge Covered
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge   Stairs(45)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge   Stairs(48)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge   Stairs(50)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Footbridge   Stairs(54)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Lift(18)
zSet_Lifts
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Lift(19)
zSet_Lifts
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Lift(35)
zSet_Lifts
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Lift(36)
zSet_Lifts
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Lift(4)
zSet_Lifts
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Lift(5)
zSet_Lifts
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Platform Face(43)
zSet_Platform face
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Platform Face(44)
zSet_Platform face
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Platform Face(51)
zSet_Platform face
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Platform Face(52)
zSet_Platform face
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Ramp(21)
zSet_Incline & Ramps
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Set-down/Pick-up   (Informal)(15)
zSet_Set Down
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Stairs - &   halls or landings(17)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Stairs - &   halls or landings(20)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Stairs - &   halls or landings(3)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Stairs - &   halls or landings(32)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Stairs - &   halls or landings(41)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Stairs - &   halls or landings(42)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Taxi rank(22)
zSet_Taxi rank
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Taxi rank(8)
zSet_Taxi rank
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Toilets   (Disabled)(38)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Toilets   (Public)(39)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
ABW


zBlock_Abbey Wood Stn Toilets   (Public)(40)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
ABW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(11)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(12)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(15)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(15)
zSet_Steps & Stairs
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(17)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(2)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(20)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(21)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(5)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Access Route(7)
zSet_Access Route
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Baby Changing   facilities(29)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Bus stop(10)
zSet_Bus Stop
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Bus stop(14)
zSet_Bus Stop
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Bus stop(6)
zSet_Bus Stop
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Bus stop(8)
zSet_Bus Stop
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Car Parking -   Disabled(1)
zSet_Access Parking
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Concourse (Whole)(23)
zSet_Concourse
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Concourse (Whole)(23)
zSet_Gateline
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Concourse (Whole)(23)
zSet_Ticket - Service-Retail Vending
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Cycle Locker(16)
zSet_Cycle Parking
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Cycle Parking   (shelter/rack)(13)
zSet_Cycle Parking
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Cycle Parking   (shelter/rack)(9)
zSet_Cycle Parking
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Cycle rack(18)
zSet_Cycle Parking
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Cycle rack(19)
zSet_Cycle Parking
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Norwich
zSet_QA Questions
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Norwich
zSet_Station
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Platform Face(25)
zSet_Platform face
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Platform Face(26)
zSet_Platform face
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Platform Face(27)
zSet_Platform face
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Platform Face(28)
zSet_Platform face
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Platform Face(33)
zSet_Platform face
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Platform Face(34)
zSet_Platform face
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Set-down/Pick-up Point   (Formal)(3)
zSet_Set Down
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Taxi rank(4)
zSet_Taxi rank
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Ticket Hall(22)
zSet_Other Space
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Ticket Hall(22)
zSet_Ticket - Service-Retail Vending
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Toilets (Disabled)(31)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Toilets (Public)(30)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Toilets (Public)(32)
zSet_Sanitary facilities
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Waiting room
zSet_Waiting Room
NRW


zBlock_Norwich Stn Waiting room(24)
zSet_Waiting Room
NRW



Asset Table

It looks like we can use DAX + visual filter to get what you want. However, pls provide some sample data (not the screenshot, not the table visual ) and the expected output.

I'm not sure how best to share the sample data, I couldn't see an option for sharing a csv. I have pasted in some lines from a csv. I think the expected output will be a asset table with filters on it like I've mentioned above. I can fairly easily create a matrix visual to display station code as rows, block groups as columns and assets as values. But maybe it needs to be outputed as a table as well in the model.

@GilWadsworth, please use https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables to markdown that table, please

Done @FrancescoMantovani
